# How to register my own firefox extension?

Tags: windows-7, firefox-addon, firefox3.6, browser-extension

I am trying to learn how to write firefox extensions. I download an HelloWorld example from [here](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Getting_started_with_extension_development#reg-em) but I can't figure out how to register it.

I found my profiles extension folder (Easy since I use the latest Firefox version) but couldn't really understand what is this "Pointer file" that I need to create (tried a shortcut but it didn't work).

What is this "Pointer File"?
How can I register it correctly?
I am using Win 7 if matters.

Thank You.

Comment: [This extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/7434/) can create the pointer file for you automatically, among several other things. Look for something that says "Install for development"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a file in the extensions folder with the ID of the add-on as name (e.g. `helloworld@mozilla.doslash.org`). This file should contain only one line which is the absolute path to the folder where the add-on is contained (e.g. `C:\\my\path\to\addon` (or however windows paths look like)).

Comment: This presentation contains an example: http://presentation-slides.googlecode.com/files/how-to-write-your-first-extension-berlin.pdf

Comment: I tried short cuts and other options. Somehow it didn't occur to me that it can be a file. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The add-on name is located inside of the install.rdf file.  Usually, it's a GUID string, but for the demo it will look like an email address.

The filename will need to match that exactly and be free of any .txt extensions, so be careful your text editor doesn't automatically give it an extension.

Comment: "Usually, it's a GUID string, but for the demo it will look like an email address." - actually it used to have to be a GUID a loooong time ago and there's no reason not to use the email-like syntax these days.