# firefox how to periodically update my own addon

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, auto-update

Is there any function to update my own Firefox add-on in my subordinates' systems or how it is being updated? I referred the below link.

[How to register my own firefox extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4580551/how-to-register-my-own-firefox-extension)

But above link is not about update.

Comment: I have no experience with Firefox extensions, but I have developed a Chrome extension. What I did to not need updates, was only include enough code to request the JavaScript from my server and run that. It meant that my extension did not work offline, but it did allow me to update it silently without any notification to anyone or doing anything harder than editing the file on my web server.

Comment: If you upload your addon to addons.mozilla.org (AMO) whenever you update it there, the update is pushed to all clients within 24hours. There is a way to supply a custom update url to your serve but I dont have experience with it, if you want though I can look into it for you when I have time.

Comment: Yes Noitidart. I want to know that also. I am glad you do that for me. I am also checking with your keyword 'custom update url'.